# Azure Storage blobs Could not load file or assembly 'System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource, Version=4.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have a console app program on `.Net core 2.2` to upload a file to the Azure blob storage. It's completely ok and working on my local computer, But when I deploy the app to the Azure app service, it throws an exception with this error:

`Could not load file or assembly 'System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource, Version=4.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd`
the problem is on this line of code:

`BlobServiceClient storageAccount = new BlobServiceClient("connection string")`

I tried to change the versions of `System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource` and `Azure.Storage.Blobs` but it didn't work on the Azure app  service

Edit:
I didn't find any solution for the problem, I change the code so that use Azure storage from the aps.net core app.

Answer (score 7):

3 Possible ways that may solve this issue

**1.** Install-Package System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource -Version 4.4.1  and add nuget package `System.Net.Http 4.3.1` to the project. Then  restart and run again.

**2.**  In the web.config file, add the following bindingRedirect tag:

```html
<dependentAssembly>
 <assemblyIdentity name="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource"
 publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" 
 culture="neutral"/>
 <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.4.1" newVersion="4.0.4.1"/>
</dependentAssembly>
```

(If you are using app.config , remove all binding redirects and addbelow property up on the top.)

```html
<AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
```

Save this and restart the app service and run the installation again.

See if this works ,other wise go for 3

**3.** Disable Application Insights using the Portal. Restart and run again.

Also try adding below property group to the *.csproj file

```html
<PropertyGroup>
  <GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>true</GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: I tried to change the version of System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource but it didn't work because I have another package in my project ```Azure.Storage.Blobs``` and it needs System.diagnostics..DiagnosticSource  version >4.6.0

The application insight is disabled

Comment: Hi @MehdiSheikh , have you tried uninstalling System.diagnostics..DiagnosticSource and installing its upgraded version >4.6.0 or by adding bindingRedirect tag in the dependent assembly(as mentioned in 2nd possible way)?

Comment: I used the exact same code in ASP.NET Core application in Azure and it's completely ok.
But in this console app, it doesn't work on Azure while it's working in local system
I tried to remove System.Diagnostic... and it still works on local system

Comment: I tried second options too, it didn't work. I added the system.diagnostic.... v4.6.0 and added dependant assembly. Also, I tried 3rd possible and still have problem in azure...

Comment: Option 1 made it for me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :
Edit Project File and add this :

`<PackageReference Include="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" Version="6.0.0" />`